# Joe was fighting with Mary

Tags: difference, present-tense, past-continuous

Dad got home and saw his son Joe and his daughter, Mary, were taking a time-out (punishment).

He asked Mom, "What's the matter?"

I know it is OK for Mom to say "Joe fought with Mary". But is it OK to say the following sentences?

> Joe was fighting with Mary.

> Joe has been fighting with Mary.

The first sentence doesn't tell us when the fight began or ended; it just says they were in the process of fighting some unspecified time ago.

The second sentence doesn't tell us when the fight began or ended, either; like the first one, it just says they were in the process of fighting some unspecified time ago.

It seems that in this context the past continuous and the present perfect continuous have the same meaning. How strange!

Comment: Stephen, please edit your question to tell us what you already know about these tenses so we don't reinvent the wheel answering it. Do you think they're correct? What do you think the differences are? Have you looked them up to see what online sources say?

Comment: Yes, both would be idiomatic. She could mean either "They were fighting at the time that I decided to punish them" or "They have been fighting (it happened a little while ago)." Either would sound more natural than "Joe fought with Mary".